# Restrict user for specific type of Biometric Authentication?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, localauthentication

**Hy,**
I want to develop an app in which users are first restricted for fingerprint authentication and after fingerprint authentication, users will be restricted to face id authentication.
But when I use Local_auth.authenticate it gives the option to the user either want to scan fingerprint or face id how can I fix this.

Comment: iOS devices have either fingerprint or face identification.  Not both

Comment: Yes, If the device doesn't support any type of biometric then the app will not ask for that.

Comment: You should probably remove the iOS tag since the question doesn't make sense for iOS

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below the code:

```
Future<void> _authenticateMe() async {
// 8. this method opens a dialog for fingerprint authentication.
//    we do not need to create a dialog nut it popsup from device natively.
bool authenticated = false;
try {
  authenticated = await _localAuthentication.authenticateWithBiometrics(
    localizedReason: "Authenticate for Testing", // message for dialog
    useErrorDialogs: true,// show error in dialog
    stickyAuth: true,// native process

  );
  print('support device try: '+authenticated.toString());
} catch (e) {
  print('support device catch: '+e.toString());
  print(e);
}
if (!mounted) return;
setState(() {
  _authorizedOrNot = authenticated ? "Authorized" : "Not Authorized";
});

if(_authorizedOrNot == 'Authorized'){
  Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen()));
}
```

}

Comment: I have tried the given code but on authentication, It gives the option to the user either want to authenticate with fingerprint or face Id.

Comment: It's for only fingerprint